# Can't post new track via PHP Soundcloud API

Tags: php, soundcloud

I'm in a bit of a pickle here. I developped a Wordpress plugin that helps my site publish sounds to soundcloud directly from the WP back-office. The site has been live for about a year, and I have had no problems until now.

When uploading a track, I get a 'Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception' with message 'The requested URL responded with HTTP code 422.'

I checked if nothing on my code had changed, and it hasn't, the request seems properly formed. Here is the bit of code:

```
$soundcloud->setAccessToken($_POST['access_token']);

  $mytrack = array(
    'track[title]' => $_POST["audioname"],
    'track[asset_data]' => $_FILES["audiofile"]["tmp_name"]
     );

  $track = json_decode($soundcloud->post('tracks', $mytrack));
```

Any idea what could be wrong? I have a Pro Unlimited account, so I can't have reached a quota, can I? Other functions used through the API work properly...

Comment: can you print out the result of `$_POST["audioname"]` & `$_FILES["audiofile"]["tmp_name"]`? 422 is Unprocessible entity. http://www.restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/422_-_Unprocessable_Entity

Comment: With pleasure @snkashis, here is the $mytrack array:

    `Array ( [track[title]] => Title [track[asset_data]] => /tmp/phpx9QfO5 )` 

Here is $_POST["audioname"] : 

    `Title`

And here is $_FILES : 

    `Array ( [audiofile] => Array ( [name] => 01-schultz.mp3 [type] => audio/mp3 [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpx9QfO5 [error] => 0 [size] => 3137898 ) )`

Comment: Anyone? I think my request is properly formed though...

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a 422 http code. That's 'Unprocessable entity' error acording to the docs. What it probably mean is that you data structure is wrong.

I don't know the php library you're using but I invite you to try out my own opensource library. https://github.com/njasm/soundcloud . Check the readme. You have an example on how to upload tracks.