# Having trouble posting a new track to Soundcloud, 422

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, soundcloud

I'm looking for some help while trying to post a new track to Soundcloud.  I have successfully authenticated the user, but having trouble, perhaps, with the format of the data I am sending to Soundcloud while trying to post a track.  Here is my code:

```
  client = Soundcloud.new(:access_token => current_user.access_token)

  sound = params[:sc_upload][:sound]
  title = params[:title]

  track = client.post('/tracks', track: {
     :title   => title,
     :asset_data => File.new(sound.tempfile.path, 'rb')
    })
```

Expecting a different response, I then tried storing the file in public/uploads then accessing it like so:

```
  track = client.post('/tracks', track: {
     :title   => title,
     :asset_data => open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', sound.original_filename).to_s)
    })
```

Receiving, still the 422 error, I tried this for fun: asset_data: sound, where sound is the ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile < Object.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html

```
  sound = #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f922c55c920 @content_type="audio/x-wav", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"sc_upload[sound]\"; filename=\"1980s-Casio-Violin-C5.wav\"\r\nContent-Type: audio/x-wav\r\n",
  @original_filename="1980s-Casio-Violin-C5.wav", @tempfile=<File:/var/folders/h1/bhw9lw797d35shc2fkws70g00000gn/T/RackMultipart201505 8-2513-8r2tq7>>
```

I have been receiving a SoundCloud::ResponseError (HTTP status: 422 Unprocessable Entity) every time.  I would appreciate any help on this.  Could be related to: [Can't post new track via PHP Soundcloud API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30277918/cant-post-new-track-via-php-soundcloud-api).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I posted [Can't post new track via PHP Soundcloud API.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30277918/cant-post-new-track-via-php-soundcloud-api) I think this is definitely related and a recent issue in the API. Glad it's not just happening to me @bagofcole ;) Any feedback from the Soundcloud team would be greatly appreciated. Especially since it doesn't seem to be PHP specific.